# How do i open a file from different path(not the server default path) using file_put_content in php

Tags: php, file, path

Is there any way to `file_put_contents` from different path i mean instead of

> c/programfiles/../../htdocs/test.txt using c/test/test.txt

the below is the code i am using:

```
$date=current_date;

$file = "test_"$date".txt";

$contents = "testtest";

file_put_contents($file, $contents);
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: yes you can use a relative or full path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When placing files on your computer you can either use relative or absolute path like this:

```
// absolute path
$file = "C:/temp/test.txt";

// relative path from C:/Program Files/wamp/htdocs/index.php
$file = "../../temp/test.txt";
```

Both of those files point to the same place